# Comparing exact expressions vs real numbers

Tags: numerical-value

Often I need to generate some data using some symmetry operations and I usually keep them as exact expressions (for example, consider the points on a triangular grid `{{-(1/2), Sqrt[3]/2}, {-(1/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {1, 0}, ...}`) and I need to compare different points, something like if `a1+b==a2`. I am trying to find an efficient way to do that.

Consider this

```
a=-2/Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[3]
b=Sqrt[1/4 + (2/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[3]/2)^2]

{N[a],N[b]}
```

> {0.57735,0.57735}

Now, `a==b` does not do anything.

```
N[a] == N[b]
N[a]-N[b] == 0
N[a - b] == 0
```

> True
>
> False
>
> False

Because `N[a-b]=-3.33067*10^-16`. So the way out is

```
Chop@N[a - b] == 0
```

> True

However,

```
RepeatedTiming[N[a] == N[b]]
RepeatedTiming[Chop@N[a - b] == 0]
```

> {5.4*10^-6, True}
>
> {9.07*10^-6, True}

On the other hand,

```
a1 = N[a]; b1 = N[b];
RepeatedTiming[a1 == b1]
```

> {2.7*10^-7, True}

So my questions are

1. Is it better to use real numbers if I have to do such comparisons?
2. What would be the best (least time consuming when dealing with a large number of inputs) way to compare exact expressions if I have to use exact expressions?

Comment: You'll want to be careful if you find cases like [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostInteger.html). `N[Sin[2017 2^(1/5)]] - N[-1]`

Comment: `PossibleZeroQ` could help.

Comment: @J.M. Damn, this almost integer stuff is fascinating. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`PossibleZeroQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html) is rather fast and does precisely what you're looking for:

```
RepeatedTiming[PossibleZeroQ[a - b]]
```

> {3.2*10^-6, True}

@JM's difficult case is handled correctly:

```
PossibleZeroQ[Sin[2017 2^(1/5)] - (-1)]
```

> False

The limits of `PossibleZeroQ` can be fine-tuned with `$MaxExtraPrecision`.